# Predicting values and confidence intervals of predictions with the pcse package

Tags: r, regression, lm, predict

we ran an OLS regression using the standard `lm` function. To address issues with the panel data we rerun the analysis with the `pcse` package to calculate the panel corrected standard errors. We got the results and wanted to generate a graphic to display the predicted values and confidence intervals (as we did for the normal `lm` regression with standard SEs) but instead we got this error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "pcse"
```

Any idea how to get the `pcse` calculated se into a `lm` object class in order to predict?

You find our model and the graph function below. We are thankful for any suggestions on how to solve this issue, that is, find a way to come up with a graphic that displays what we want it to display

Greetz

Model:

```
m.2 <- lm(PIV~inter_X1+inter_X2+X3+X1+DumX2+X4+X5, data=Dataset))
summary(m.2)

m.2<-  pcse(lm(PIV~(X3*X1)+(X3*X2)+X3+X1+X2+X4+X5, data=Dataset), 
    groupN = Dataset$C1, groupT = Dataset$Y)
pred.val <- predict(m.2, newdata=Dataset_2, 
   se.fit=TRUE, interval=c("confidence"), level=0.9)
## Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
##  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "pcse"
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adjusting your title because the answer to your original question ("Why can't R ...?") is trivial and not terribly useful: because the package authors didn't write a `predict()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need something along these lines to get the adjusted standard errors of the predictions (adapted from http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq):

```
lmFit <- ...
form <- formula(lmFit)[-2]  ## RHS of formula
Designmat <- model.matrix(form,data=Dataset) 
## note that your model could be written more compactly as ~X3*(X1+X2)+X4+X5
vv <- vcovPC(lmFit,...)
pred <- Designmat %*% coef(lmFit)  ## or predict(lmFit,newdata=Dataset)
predvar <- diag(Designmat %*% vv %*% t(Designmat)) 
se <- sqrt(predvar)   ## for confidence intervals
se2 <- sqrt(predvar+summary(lmFit)$sigma^2)  ## for prediction intervals
qq <- qnorm((1-level)/2)
interval <- pred+qq*cbind(se,-se)
```

A [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) would be nice, I don't have time to make one up right now ...

Comment: Is it still the case that: "predict method (missing from stable lme4)"?

Comment: no, that's out of date.  But confidence intervals are still missing because we can't convince ourselves it's OK to offer CIs that don't incorporate uncertainty in the variance-covariance parameters ...

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own method, using the code for other packages' methods as a template.

But in the short term, it's probably a lot easier to grab the coefficient values from your `m.2` object.   `m.2$coefficients` contains all the fitting coefficients, labelled as to which term they belong to.  You'll then have to write a little function to match the algebraic form of your `PIV~(X3*X1)+(X3*X2)+X3+X1+X2+X4+X5` formula, with those coefficients applied.